# Можно ли из массива с разными типами данных, выводить на экран определенный тип

Tags: javascript

```
var arr= ['Andrey','Dima','Alexey', 1,2,3,4];
```

Comment: Желательно с помощью цикла for

Comment: `for (let el of arr){console.log(typeof el)}`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = ['Andrey','Dima','Alexey', 1,2,3,4];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Можно.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [1, 22, 44, 'Hello', 'World'];

//for (let el of arr){console.log(typeof el)} //вывод типов элементов

function showType(type){
  for (let el of arr){
    if (typeof el === type){
    console.log(el)
    }
  }
}

console.log('вывод элементов с типом string:');

showType('string'); // вывод элементов с типом string

console.log('вывод элементов с типом number:');

showType('number'); // вывод элементов с типом number
```

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй самый эстетичный и короткий вариант - использование фильтра:

```js
var arr = ['Andrey', 'Dima', 'Alexey', 1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log( arr.filter(e => typeof e === 'string') );
```

А также можно сделать это с помощью простого цикла

```js
var arr = ['Andrey', 'Dima', 'Alexey', 1, 2, 3, 4];

for(let e of arr) {
  if(typeof e === 'string') {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

В обоих случаях мы выводим только элементы типа `string`